# How to Trigger openLayers 3 'singleClick' from karma test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, openlayers-3, karma-coverage

I am using angular2 and openlayers3 to display a map on our page.
Following singleClick feature is used to show a popup when marker on map is clicked -

```
        this.map.on('singleclick', (e) => {
            this.showWellDetails(e.pixel);
        });
```

This works perfectly fine, but I have no way to trigger is from my karma test.
Hence this block of code is not getting covered.

**Edit - Added code for test case as well here -**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test-component-wrapper',
    template: '<map [markers]="markers"  [isDocked]="isDocked" ></map>',
})
class TestComponentWrapper {
    public isDocked = true;
    public markers = [
        {
            "latitude": 101.106074,
            "longitude": 1.307283,
            "name": "211/27-A17",
        },
        {
            "latitude": 61.034344,
            "longitude": 1.703716,
            "name": "211/29-A17",
        },
    ];
}
describe('MapComponent events', () => {
    let component: MapComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponentWrapper>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                TestComponentWrapper,
                MapComponent,
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        })
            .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponentWrapper);
        component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should test showDetails functionality', () => {
        component.isDocked = false;
        component.initMap();
        expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#mapId'))).not.toBe(null);
        let pixel = [
            233.10227584838867,
            191.25,
        ];

        // I want to trigger 'singleClick' on map from here...
        // component.map.singleClick();
        // Since this is not working, I have to make showWellDetails function public and call it directly.
        //at least it adds coverage for this function, but the original block of code mentioned above remains uncovered.


        component.showWellDetails(pixel);
        expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#featureDetails'))).toBe(null);
        expect(component.locationCoordinate).toBeUndefined();
    });
    //other tests
});
```

Any help is appreciated! TIA.

Comment: Please, could you post your unit testing code?

Comment: @SrAxi - Added the test code in the post Edit

Comment: Hey - can anyone help me with this please ?

Answer (score 0):

How I finally achieved it might help others who are looking for this information -

```
public singleClickCallback = (e) => {
        this.showWellDetails(e.pixel);
 }

 this.map.on('singleclick', this.singleClickCallback);
```